# Network is Unreachable (whois, ping)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have been browsing around the forums and can't seem to find an answer that works for me. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a vm, with Windows 10 as the host machine, connected to the internet with NAT.  When I try to do a whois, or ping outside the network I get the error

```
$whois google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Tools like dig and wget both work fine, and I can access the web through the browser, here are some of the usual command outputs for debugging

**Dig:**

```
$dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7759
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     5   IN  A   216.58.219.206

;; Query time: 2029 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 01 09:31:49 EST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

**Ping:**

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.219.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
35 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 34075ms
```

**Ifconfig:**

```
$ifconfig ens33
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:81:b4:9e  
          inet addr:192.168.93.137  Bcast:192.168.93.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cb32:1559:ed2e:9968/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:399609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:111912 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:318681424 (318.6 MB)  TX bytes:17133081 (17.1 MB)
```

**Route**

```
$route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.93.2    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens33
192.168.93.0    *
```

**/etc/networking/interfaces**

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

I am using Oh My ZSH, but I dont think that would affect this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your route output look wrong ..I would expect it to be in the opposite order. Also the last line is missing 6 fields.

Comment: What flavor of VM is this? IIRC for VirtualBox, the default NAT range is 10.x.x.x - have you change that, and if so did you by any chance make it the same subnet as the host?

Comment: @SorenA that last line was just from trying something out someone suggested, it wasn't there originally

Comment: @steeldriver Its VMware Workstation, I have not changed the NAT range at all

Comment: As wget, browser an dig are working (the default protocols HTTP/DNS), but not WHOIS (port 43) and PING (ICMP), this seems to be an issue with some sort of firewall (in your VM, VMWare or the windows host...). Try `ping 192.168.93.2`, which is the network endpint in VMWare, then `ping <IP-of-your-host>` etc. to find out where this stops.

Comment: @ridgy Thanks, when looking for the host IP I noticed for some reason they were on different subnets, I switched from NAT to bridged, and that seemed to solve the issue somehow

Comment: same issues here.. opening port 43 also worked fine